# Change object color in Edit Mode

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Perhaps it's simpler than it may seem but I can't find the right way.
In my Editor I have a MonoBehaviour that I run with [ExecuteInEditMode]. In this script I have the following code:

```
void OnGUI() {
    Event e = Event.current;
    Vector3 mousePosition = e.mousePosition;
    mousePosition.y = Screen.height - mousePosition.y;
    Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
    RaycastHit hitInfo;
    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hitInfo, 100f)) {
        if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.name.Contains("MySphere")) {
           go_highlight = GameObject.Find(hitInfo.transform.gameObject.name);
           go_highlight.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial.color = Color.yellow;
        } 
    [...]
```

In another part of the code I restore the color of the sphere if the cursor is not above it.
In the scene I have several spheres and I need to highlight the one below the mouse pointer.
What I get though is that all the spheres are highlighted and not just the one under the cursor. I guess it's for "sharedMaterial" but I can't use "Material" because it returns an error.
I could also attach a script to the spheres with OnMouseEnter and OnMouseExit but I have to work in Edit Mode and these methods don't seem to work even with [ExecuteInEditMode].

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: instead of directly changing the material, since they share a material hence the name `sharedMaterial`, you could then use OnDrawGizmos method to draw a line toa sphere at the same location and scale as the hovered object.

Comment: Following your suggestion I realized that the Gizmos could also be picked. I'm evaluating if I can change my spheres with Gizmos. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest that instead of changing the colour; you change the material of that object.

For example:

1. obj has material (1)
2. material (1) is red
3. when moused over obj changes to material (2)
4. material (2) is blue

To allow this change

```
go_highlight.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().sharedMaterial.color = Color.yellow;
```

To

```
go_highlight.GetComponent<MeshRenderer>().material = material (2);
```

This is a simplified solution, to match your code however there are more effective ways of achieving this.

Comment: Thanks, I hadn't really thought about it.